# How to implement callbacks asynchronously in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am building a web app, using Django, which has two parts:

1. deploy docker containers and store the expiry time in the database,
2. according to the expiry time kill them, however, a user of the app can choose to extend the life of the container.

How do I implement the second part without polling on the database?

I tried using asyncio and implemented a custom middleware in Django but it blocks the execution. Is there any other way which does the job asynchronously.

```
import asyncio
from threading import Thread


def callback_func(eventloop):
    """
    check DB
    if now:
        kill
    else:
        register a new callback with new updated time 
    """
    # Logic to kill a container goes here

    print ("Inside callback")


class KillerMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        self._eventloop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(self._eventloop)

        self._t = Thread(target=lambda : self._eventloop.run_forever())
        self._t.daemon = True
        self._t.start()


    def __call__(self, request):

        response = self.get_response(request)

        self._eventloop.call_later(86400, callback_func, self._eventloop)
        return response
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know much about `python-asyncio`, but it sounds like [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) would be right for this.